# How to get notified when a previously connected peripheral re-connects later (a connection originating from peripheral)?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

So I am building an IoT device and now I am working on battery optimizations. I am able to tell the device to connect to a central it has bonded to. This works(ish). You can observe the device connecting in bluetooth settings, but about 5 seconds later it disconnects. I would assume that since there is nothing happening and nothing asking for it, it drops the connection. I also assume that this is allowed for ANCS. What I want to know is can it be used for anything else? I would like to be able to shut off the device, not have to scan constantly in app, and have the system notify my central manager that the device has connected later (when a user wakes it up.

I know I can call

```
[_manager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:identifiers];
```

to get devices I have connected to before, but I am not seeing a way to attach unconnected ones to the manager so that when they do connect in the background, the app knows about it. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: You need to just have a pending `connect` from your central. The connection will complete when iOS sees your peripheral you will get a `didConnect` callback.

Comment: This is true. Thank you. Though, without having my peripheral advertise it seems to take a long time.

With no advertising, I can have the peripheral request a connection, and it weirdly takes about 30s, then I see a disconnect called, then authentication, link Key exchanges, the a new connection that is taken up by my app. Any thoughts on that?